# Spring JpaSpecificationExecutor no property findAll found for type Alarm

Tags: java, spring, jpa, redis, specifications

I use Redis to store my application's alarms with entity as below:

```
@RedisHash("alarm")
public class Alarm implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @Indexed
    private String name;

    @Indexed
    private String createdAt;

    @Indexed
    private String createdBy;

    @Indexed
    private String clearAt;

    @Indexed
    private String clearBy;
}
```

Data source configuration is like below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisRepositories(basePackages = "com.app.demo.redis.repository")
public class RedisDataSourceConfiguration {

@Autowired
private RedisProperties redisProperties;

@Bean
public JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory(){
    RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
    return new JedisConnectionFactory();
    }

@Bean
public RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate(){
    RedisTemplate<Object, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<Object, Object>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
    }
}
```

And this is repository:

```
@Repository
public interface AlarmRedisRepository extends JpaRepository<Alarm, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Alarm>{
}
```

I used `Specification` to customize the search:

```
public class AlarmSpecification implements Specification<Alarm>{
    private Alarm filter;

    public AlarmSpecification(Alarm alarm){
        this.alarm = alarm;
    }

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Alarm> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder){
            // This is where I added the filter
            Predicate predicate = builder.disjunction();
            return predicate;
    }
}
```

In my `@Service`:

```
@Autowired
private AlarmRedisRepository repo;


Pageable pageable = .....
Alarm alarm = .....
Specification<Alarm> specification = new AlarmSpecification(alarm);
Page<Alarm> page = repo.findAll(specification, pageable);
```

it returns the error as the titlte. Anybody who used to work with Redis and Specification can help me !!! Thank in advanced

Comment: You are using Redis not a SQL database. So why do you use JPA?

Comment: since I wanted to handle data in Redis like in other databases and also Spring supports @RedishHash to do that

Comment: But you can't! JPA is only for SQL databases

Comment: so what you mean is there is no way that this `findAll(Specification, Pageable)` can work :-(

Comment: Please read the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#reference